# Connection String Issue

Tags: asp.net, connection-string

I have just bought web hosting with 123.reg and have uploaded my asp.net site and database.

My web.config file currently has the following as the connection string:

```
    <connectionStrings>
    <add name="RaiseConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=MATT-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Raise;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

The issue comes however with with 123.reg account, as it requires the connection string format to be:

```
    <appSettings>
<add key="ConnectionString" value="Server=ATLAS-SQL-07; Database=Raise; User Id=Raise; Password=******" /> 
</appSettings>
```

By changing this I get an error in my application as it cannot find the connection string Raise. How can I rectify this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work in your web.config file:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="RaiseConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=Server=ATLAS-SQL-07;Initial Catalog=Raise;User Id=Raise; Password=******;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/> 
</connectionStrings>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to change the key to `ConnectionString` - your original key of `RaiseConnectionString` is probably ok. The hosting account was just telling you what the value of the connection string should be.

Comment: I tried using:

<appSettings>
<add key="RaiseFantasyLeagueConnectionString" value="Server=ATLAS-SQL-07; Database=Raise; User Id=Raise; Password=******" /> 
</appSettings>

but it didn't work, it causes an error stating 'the connection name was not found'